# How to update only those rows which are updated in loop?

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, asp.net-core

I have an application which keeps updating every 1 second and I need to update my database accordingly.

I have this following `getOrg` function which grabs the data from API endpoint and insert into the database, but before inserting it checks hash for the duplicates, till here it works really well. But the problem is if something changes there will be new hash and as its a new hash it will go ahead and try to insert record but as OrgGuid is my primary key it is giving me:

> SqlException: Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint

So my question is how can I update only those columns which got changed?

```
public async Task getOrg()
{
    var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, "organizations");
    var response = await _client_NP.SendAsync(request);
    var json = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    OrganizationsClass.OrgsRootObject model = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<OrganizationsClass.OrgsRootObject>(json);

    foreach (var item in model.resources)
    {
        string tmpmasterhash = HashClass.CreateMD5(item.guid + item.name + item.created_at + item.updated_at);

        if (!_DBcontext.Organizations.Any(o => o.Orghash == tmpmasterhash))
        {
            var Orgs = new Organizations
            {
                OrgGuid = Guid.Parse(item.guid),
                Name = item.name,
                CreatedAt = item.created_at,
                UpdatedAt = item.updated_at,
                Orghash = tmpmasterhash,
                Timestamp = DateTime.Now,
                Foundation = 3
            };
            _DBcontext.Organizations.Add(Orgs);
        }
    }

    await _DBcontext.SaveChangesAsync();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Retrieve the organization for the given Guid first, and if it exists, update it. If it doesn't exist, add it

```
var g = Guid.Parse(item.guid);
var x = _DBcontext.Organizations.FirstOrDefault(o => o.OrgGuid == g);
if(x == null)
  _DBcontext.Organizations.Add(new Organizations
                {
                    OrgGuid = g,
                    Name = item.name,
                    CreatedAt = item.created_at,
                    UpdatedAt = item.updated_at,
                    Orghash = tmpmasterhash,
                    Timestamp = DateTime.Now,
                    Foundation = 3
                });
else{
  x.Name = item.name;
  .... //whatever else you want to update
}

await _DBcontext.SaveChangesAsync();
```

PS; if the hash changes it's not a good idea to dedupe based on it; by definition you have an ID that doesn't change, don't bother with your hash - use the Guid you use for the PK?

---

Per my comment, hash is really only useful to know whether you should run a DB update, but honestly, it's probably useless. I would expect that EF won't bother to save the object if you update the properties to the same values they are already so calcing a hash is a waste of time but here's how you might:

```
var g = Guid.Parse(item.guid);
var x = _DBcontext.Organizations.FirstOrDefault(o => o.OrgGuid == g);
if(x == null){
  _DBcontext.Organizations.Add(new Organizations
                {
                    OrgGuid = g,
                    Name = item.name,
                    CreatedAt = item.created_at,
                    UpdatedAt = item.updated_at,
                    Orghash = tmpmasterhash,
                    Timestamp = DateTime.Now,
                    Foundation = 3
                });
  await _DBcontext.SaveChangesAsync();
} else if(tmpmasterhash  != x.Orghash) {
  x.Name = item.name;
  .... //whatever else you want to update
  await _DBcontext.SaveChangesAsync();
}
```

Comment: This way I'm eliminating hash check, but I need hash checking

Comment: What do you need hash checking for? It flat out doesn't work to prove whether the entity exists in your DB or not, so it can't be used for that. At best it could be used to know whether you should bother updating/saving in the ELSE in my code..

Comment: for the duplicates checking but I guess with this approach I will not need

Comment: Sure make sense

Comment: Yeah, the problem you've got is that for the DB you've decided one method of uniquely identifying an object (use a guid) and then in the code youre deciding another way to uniquely identify an object (hash it) - these two aren't compatible if the guid can stay the same but the hash can change, meaning that the code thinks the object is new but the db thinks it is not new. The db and the code have to be aligned on how they choose to decide one object is equal to another

Answer (score 1):

**Attach**

Attaches a record to the context. This is optimistic behavior: Entity Framework expects the record to exist and only observes other records that make use of this attached record. Any modifications made to the attached record are not passed on to the database.

Read this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/saving/change-tracking/entity-state

Original answer: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/38195/14630